# Reattaching remote servers: no such file or directory in terminal

Tags: terminal, network, remote-desktop, mount

I'm using the `Connect to Server` tool to mount a remote drive.  I'm able to access this via `Terminal` at `/Volumes/REMOTE`.  If I unmount and remount the same connection however, my existing terminal windows can't reconnect --- I have to open new terminal windows.  Is there any way around this behavior?

e.g.

```
$ cd /Volumes/REMOTE
$ ls
Desktop    envs    intel    
<un-mount>
<re-mount>
$ pwd
/Volumes/REMOTE
$ ls
ls: .: No such file or directory
```

If I have an emacs session open with a remote file, and the connection is lost and reconnected (un-mounted, and re-mounted), the session still works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of El Capitan, OSX 10.11.0, this is no longer an issue.  Terminal is now able to recover once the remote server has been remounted.